# laravel the "" file does not exist or is not readable for files bigger than 2mb

Tags: laravel, file-upload

Local machine is working 100% with every file size and my problem is on production server.

I still have no problem uploading files less than 2mb, 
this error is only happening when i upload file more than 2mb. 
i tried updating max file size in php.ini to 20M and restart nginx and php-fpm.

I've tried  `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and added these:

```
http{
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        client_body_timeout 300s;

        ...
}
```

I've tried `sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini` and changed these:

```
post_max_size = 20M
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

I did restart my nginx and php like this:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

But still less than 2mb file upload works and more than 2mb gives me error:

```
message: "The "" file does not exist or is not readable."
```

PS:
i also used `sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com` and added `client_max_body_size 20M;` before `listen 80;` but still getting same error after restarting nginx and php7.2-fpm.

I printed phpInfo() and my post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are still 2 mb!
I dont know why my phpInfo is not getting updated as well.

Comment: Have you tried several files bigger than 2mb?

Comment: yes i have tried many files, same files working on local. but giving error on production server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

inside the `server` block in Nginx as well.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the file with server block? because i only can see http block.

Comment: The ```http``` block can contain one or more ```server```blocks. [Here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/) is an example. They can be either explicitly declared within the ```http``` block or they can be declared inside an imported file using the ```include``` directive like this:
```include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;```

Comment: i used ```sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com``` and added ```client_max_body_size 20M; ``` before ```listen 80;``` but still no luck :(.

Comment: hey dude im still struggling , but i found something very new. i used phpInfo() and my max file size upload is still 2mb but in php ini its 20M it is not getting updated for some reason....

Comment: Then the problem is that you are hot swapping php without reloading the server using it. Either you override the config from the beginning pasting your php.ini file before launching the whole thing or you try to reload it with one of [these](https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm/506951) commands. Good luck!

Comment: I fixed the problem by completely reinstalling php in my server.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling whit this and here is how I fixed it:

> find which is my php.ini file

1. `sudo find / -name php.ini`

> edit the file
> 2) `sudo vim /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`

> edit filesizes
> 3) increase upload_max_filesize and post_max_size to whatever you need and save it

4. find your services and restart them

if you are using fpm

`sudo service --status-all | grep -i fpm` This will give you the right service you are using

> then

`sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

> then

`sudo service nginx reload`